# How to find payment details(like method of payment, amount paid etc.) in Razorpay in react?

Tags: reactjs, razorpay

I'm trying to implement razorpay as a payment method for my website,but I'm not able to figure out how to find all payment details after successful payment. Below are some method and code which I tried but not able to get the results.

```
const REACT_APP_RAZORPAY_PUBLIC_KEY="rzp_test_QadmhmrFi5r6szP"
const REACT_APP_RAZORPAY_PRIVATE_KEY="4IqirUMK8hjKvhq3XhHxpHT7";

export default function Payment() {
  const options = {
    key: REACT_APP_RAZORPAY_PUBLIC_KEY,
    amount: 13.14, //  = INR,
    description: 'Transaction Amount',
    handler: function(response) {
       alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
    },
    prefill: {
        name: "Hello",
        contact: 8453423498,
        email: hello@gmail.com
    },
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js';
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, [])

  const openPay=()=>{
    var paywindow=new window.Razorpay(options);
    paywindow.open();
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Button style={{background:"green",color:"white"}} onClick={openPay}>Pay with Razorpay</Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried some method like below, but they didn't worked.

```
var pay_instance = new Razorpay({
    key_id: REACT_APP_RAZORPAY_PUBLIC_KEY,
    key_secret: REACT_APP_RAZORPAY_PRIVATE_KEY,
  });

pay_instance.payments.fetch(response.razorpay_payment_id);
```

I also tried using request api -

```
payment_id=response.razorpay_payment_id;
var request = require('request');

request('https://REACT_APP_RAZORPAY_PUBLIC_KEY:REACT_APP_RAZORPAY_PRIVATE_KEY@api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/payment_id', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('Response:', body);
});
```

I am not able to figure out how to get all details regarding a payment. Please help.